# Why is Wifi not working on my HP laptop?

Tags: wireless

The wireless card is not working but the Internet is working good with Ethernet cable.

The output of `lspci` is :

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
```

At fist the card was working but sometimes it's disconnected, and have problem on coverage range, and sometimes it's not working at all

I tried many solutions on the Internet but now it's not working at all.

I don't know what to do :(

Comment: Please refer to: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Answer (score 5):

This [forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11446022&postcount=2) seems to have helped most people facing this issue.

I have reproduced the necessary steps here for the sake of simplicity.

---

In the *Additional Drivers* application, check for any drivers pertaining to `STA` and disable them.

Open *Terminal* and enter the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove b43-fwcutter broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source firmware-b43-installer firmware-b43-lpphy-installer firmware-b43legacy-installer bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Now, enter the following commands:

```
echo "blacklist bcma" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "blacklist brcm80211" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Reboot Ubuntu.

Open Terminal again and enter the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source firmware-b43-installer
```

After the package installation is complete, reboot.

Open *Additional Drivers*.

Enable the `Broadcom STA` driver.

Your Wifi should now be active and functional.

---

*This seems to be a [documented bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/broadcom-sta/+bug/990222).*

Comment: thx for your effort

Comment: This seems to mostly work, but I don't alway see the broadcom driver listed in the "Additional drivers"  I have two HP laptops.  My Pavilion G and my wife's Mini 10.  Her's shows nothing in "Additional drivers" except something about "Cedar"  but following all the other steps seems to get everything working.