# Improper installation of ubuntu on hp laptop

Tags: drivers, system-installation

I have hp laptop 14s-cr1005TU I have tried to install ubuntu on it. But it didn't install properly. The touch pad of my laptop and wifi doesn't work. For able to use I have to connect external mouse and wifi adapter. I think the problem is my hp laptop kernel doesn't support ubuntu. Please recommend me what to do. Do I have to install some drivers?

Comment: Try: `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-libinput ` To check that the X.org driver is installed. And for the wifi adapter please consider:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/168909/why-is-wifi-not-working-on-my-hp-laptop